terraform Invalid provider configuration
I am trying to write a module using third party provider and it's keep giving me following error
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│ The argument "base_endpoint" is required, but was not set.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid provider configuration
│
│ Provider "registry.terraform.io/djlemkes/airflow" requires explicit configuration. Add a provider block to the root module and configure the provider's required arguments as described in the provider
│ documentation.
│
╵

following is my module code
modules/airflow/roles.tf
locals {
  developer_role = jsondecode(file(var.role_json_file_path))
}


data "google_client_config" "airflow" {
  provider = google
}

provider "airflow" {
  base_endpoint = var.airflow_url
  oauth2_token  = data.google_client_config.airflow.access_token
}

resource "airflow_role" "role" {
  name = var.role_name

  dynamic "action" {
    for_each = local.developer_role
    content {
      action   = action.value.action
      resource = action.value.resource
    }
  }
}


modules/airflow/provider.tf
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.53"
    }
    airflow = {
      source  = "DJLemkes/airflow"
      version = "0.10.1"
    }
  }

}


modules/airflow/variables.tf
variable "role_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "role name for airflow"
}

variable "role_json_file_path" {
  type        = string
  description = "json file for airflow role"
}

variable "airflow_url" {
  type        = string
  description = "airflow url"
}


And this is how I am calling it.
module "def-airflow-developer" {
  source              = "modules/airflow"
  role_name           = "airflow-developer"
  role_json_file_path = "./developer_role.json"
  airflow_url         = var.test_composer_url

}




So there are two errors:

Missing base_endpoint: The airflow provider in your module needs the Airflow instance URL (base_endpoint) to be set.
Invalid Provider Configuration: Terraform needs explicit configuration for third-party providers like airflow. You have to define a provider block within your module.

The Fix:

Delete the Unnecessary provider.tf:

The separate provider.tf file is redundant because you're already configuring the provider within the roles.tf file.
Just remove the provider.tf file.





Pass the Airflow URL:

Your module's airflow provider needs base_endpoint.
Update your module call to pass the airflow_url variable from your main Terraform configuration:



module "def-airflow-developer" {
  source           = "modules/airflow"
  role_name         = "airflow-developer"
  role_json_file_path = "./developer_role.json"
  airflow_url       = var.test_composer_url  # Pass the URL from the main configuration
}



Changes you need in roles.tf:

locals {
  developer_role = jsondecode(file(var.role_json_file_path))
}

data "google_client_config" "airflow" {
  provider = google
}

provider "airflow" {
  base_endpoint = module.def-airflow-developer.airflow_url  # Access URL from module input
  oauth2_token  = data.google_client_config.airflow.access_token
}

resource "airflow_role" "role" {
  name = var.role_name

  dynamic "action" {
    for_each = local.developer_role
    content {
      action  = action.value.action
      resource = action.value.resource
    }
  }
}

This should get your Terraform module working!
Now it uses the airflow_url you provide when calling the module and configures the airflow provider directly within the module.

but then I can't reference this module at multiple places. I don't have single airflow environment.

@GaurangShah you still can, this doesn't make your module 'not resuable'
